# This code will cause kernel level memory leaks, what is the difference between this and user land memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, kernel

```
void foo()
{
    char *var = kmalloc(1, GFP_KERNEL);
    return;
}
```

This code will cause kernel level memory leaks, what is the difference between this and user land memory leaks

This is a question from a interview today. I did bad about this question.Can anyone give any thoughts?

Comment: One does not simply leak memory in kernel-land!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory leaked in userspace is reclaimed at process termination, but memory leaked in kernel space cannot be reclaimed until the machine is rebooted.

Comment: You don't need to reboot the machine, but just the executing unit. In that regard, kexec will do.